# Moving around within xml documents?

Tags: motion, xml

Are there any useful functions / modes / hydras / utilities for navigating xml documents?

Some features that might be nice to have:

- Jump to parent
- Jump to next child
- Jump to matching tag (like % in vim)
- Helm go to ancestor
- Helm to to child

## Things that I have found so far

Commands `sgml-skip-tag-forward` and `sgml-skip-tag-backward`. There is an `sgml-tag-end` function by this is not interactive and wants to take an argument.

Comment: [x-path-walker](https://melpa.org/#/x-path-walker) is looking quite nice for globally navigating around (it would be nice to do this relative to a node)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. See `nxml-mode`, option `nxml-sexp-element-flag`, and movement commands such as `nxml-forward-balanced-item`, `nxml-forward-element`, and `nxml-up-element`.
2. If you use library [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can use [Icicles search commands](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview) `icicle-search-xml-element` and `icicle-search-xml-element-text-node` for navigating among and within XML elements.

   (Non-`nil` option [`icicle-ignore-comments-flag`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Customization_and_General_Tips#icicle-ignore-comments-flag) means ignore comments for such Icicles search commands, so that XML elements that are commented out are skipped. You can toggle this during search using `C-M-;`.)